# pyamiibo vs amiiboapi.com to lookup amiibo bin dump file

Tags: python

I am trying to use pyamiibo from https://pypi.org/project/pyamiibo/ to read my amiibo bin dump file in python, and attempting to use amiiboapi.com to look up the details...

For Duck Hunt, pyamiibo's uid_hex returns "04 FC 30 82 03 49 80", but amiiboapi.com returns { "head": "07820000", "tail": "002f0002",}...

What should I do to link up the 2 outputs?

Answer (score 0):

The UID is unique to each tag, the head and tail are in pages 21 and 22 respectively

Comment: So my goal is to use pyamiibo to find what which character is in the bin file, then look up the details (like game, name and a jpg) from a website, such as amiiboapi.com... looks like my current approach doesn't work. Can you suggest how to do it? Thanks.